# What does Object reference not set to an instance of an object error mean when using Add-AzServiceFabricClusterCertificate?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-service-fabric, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to add a new secondary cert to the service fabric, however I receive the following error. does any one have any pointers?

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Add-AzServiceFabricClusterCertificate -ResourceGroupName '******'  -Name '********'  -SecretIdentifier '*************'  
Add-AzServiceFabricClusterCertificate : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-AzServiceFabricClusterCertificate -ResourceGroupName '****
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Add-AzServiceFabricClusterCertificate], NullReferenceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ServiceFabric.Commands.AddAzureRmServiceFabricClusterCertificate
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not reproduce your issue, it works on my side.

Try to update the `Az.ServiceFabric` with the command below, my version is `2.0.1`.

```
Update-Module -Name Az.ServiceFabric -Force
```

In azure keyvault, I use a self-signed certificate, make sure you use the `SecretIdentifier` below.

[image]

Then use the powershell and check the result in the portal.

```
Add-AzServiceFabricClusterCertificate -ResourceGroupName '<group-name>' -Name 'joyfabric' -SecretIdentifier 'https://joykeyvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/cer135/23c6706daeab47e59caca2431ad96a1c'
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou for your answer, I had a question, my certificate exists in secrets blade, is that an issue?

Comment: @TaherKhan You need to import your certificate to the keyvault in the certificates blade instead of secrets blade, then click it, you will find a secret url like the screenshot.